# Apex Oracle : How to refresh Page Item?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page Item on Apex 19.2

In page validation where i'm setting the value of the item : P1_MyItem. The value is set properly in session state. However it's not reflected immedialy in the html item. I still need to reload the page to get the right value in the item.

Is there any way to reflect it immediatly please ? (without reloading the page)

Thanks.
Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure *Items to Return* lists any item that is updated within the PL/SQL, that you would also like updated within the web page once the dynamic action is completed.

[image]

As opposed to 'Items to Submit', which sends any information in pages items the browser is aware of to the database, before execution of the PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 1):

Page processing now defaults to using Ajax. So, if a validation error occurs, the page is no longer re-rendered by default because the assumption is that validations will not change session state. If you want to see your changes, you'll need to locate the page property named **Reload on Submit** and set that to **Always**.

But, of course, that means the page will be re-rendered/re-loaded which is what you're trying to avoid.

Also, it's not possible to set the page property to **Reload on Submit** if you want to use an Interactive Grid on the same page. It requires the option **Only for Success**, so you have to refresh the page item somehow else.